# Is there any equivalence of `--depth immediates` in `git`?

Tags: svn, git

Currently, I'm try to setup `git` front-end to the Subversion repository.

My Subversion repository is a single large repository which consists of several co-related projects:

```
svn-root
  |-- project1
  |   |-- branches
  |   |-- tags
  |   `-- trunk
  |-- project2
  |   |-- branches
  |   |-- tags
  |   `-- trunk
  `-- project3
      |-- branches
      |-- tags
      `-- trunk
```

Because it's sometimes needs to move files between different projects, so I don't want to break the repository to separate ones.

I'm going to use `git-svn` to setup a git front-end, but I don't see how to exactly mapping the svn to git structure. The two systems treat `branches` and `tags` very different and I doubt it is possible.

To simplify the problem, I would just `git svn clone` the whole root directory and let `branches/tags/trunk` directories just sit there. But this will definitely result in too many files in `branches` and `tags` directories. In Subversion, it's easy to just set the depth of checkout to `immediates`, which will only checkout the branch/tag titles, without the directory contents. but I don't know if this can be done in `git`.

The git-svn messed me up. I hope there's more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really isn't a good way to do this.  Git does not support partial checkouts.  So either you keep it all in one repository and check it all out at once, or you use submodules and keep the file moving to a minimum.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365541/how-to-move-files-from-one-git-repo-to-another-not-a-clone-preserving-history on the latter point.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to checkout the entire history however.  The following statement only checks out the most recent changes:

```
git clone --depth 1 user@server.com:project
```

Such a checkout is NOT good for editing and checking back in, but it is great for sharing the current code base or for deploying to production, etc.